# Are evals in stack trace evils?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

On a Vue app, I discovered recently that stack trace, includes a lot of "eval".
It's the case for many Vue routines, but also when I call a function, passed by argument in a function, somewhere in Vue.

So, if I add this:

```
const A = (fB) => fB();
const B = () => true;
(() => {
    A(B);
    console.warn("Fb");
})();
```

Chrome logs:

```
Formae.js?41dd:15 Fb
eval    @   Formae.js?41dd:15
```

Sorry in advence, I will be - I'm confused, and I doubt also of my english grammar.

My first question is : Is this evil .. I mean, dangerous ? Is this a  security breach ? Is this a Vue concern ? Or is this just a Node.js, and back-end concerns, with no security implications on the front-end ?

On the other side, while I know since a long time that eval is surrounded with his evil security-weakness aura, I'm mainly concerned with the performance cost :

I use Vue to build an UI, requesting methods from objetcs, that have no directs concerns with reactivity - I just need the ouput for displaying it, when it's setted : For this reason I already freeze it in a Vue.$set method.

Should I separate totaly my methods from Vue, and call them as a fetch API would do ? In other words, should I put them on the back-end ? And launch this (Yet I don't know how can I do) with adding a command in my package.json ? (scripts: {serve:...}}

Thanks

Comment: "*if I add this*" - **where** exactly do you add this?

Comment: `eval` is evil only if you pass a user-controlled string to it. In this case it's the same as executing code inside <script>

Comment: @Bergi: Anywhere in my repository : In the main file, before 'new Vue', in the components, in classes called in the components

Comment: Then something else is at play here. Vue should have no dealings with code placed directly in the main script. Are you sure the `eval` is not part of hot module reloading or something?

Comment: @Bergi: Indeed, thanks. The stack trace in my exemple starts with webpack HMR calls !

Comment: Then no, these are neither evil nor a security concern in production.

Comment: @Bergi: Neither a performance issue outside dev build, and i’m glad the answer is almost silly as the question was formulated - thanks !